# Flutter set TextField cursor position

Tags: flutter

I have a simple `TextField` widget in my app. I noticed that the blue cursor is always at the end so that I can input more text there. However, when I tap at the beginning of my input or anywhere in the middle in order to change cursor focus position, it does not go there. It always stays there and I have to delete all input to get back there.

[image]

I have searched how to achieve this but closest I found is this small example which I do not understand.

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/flutter+texteditingcontroller+cursor+position

The following is my widget.

```
TextField(
                          controller: _descriptionTextController,
                          enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            fillColor: Colors.transparent,
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                            hintText: 'Product description',
                          ),
                          style: TextFieldStyle,
                        ),
```

Could anyone help me please.

Comment: remove or change to `true` this parameter `enableInteractiveSelection: false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Allowing other interactions along with movement of text caret**

What you want to do is to be able to move the text caret when user interacts with the text. You have set `enableInteractiveSelection` to false.

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/enableInteractiveSelection.html):

> *When this is false, the text selection cannot be adjusted by the user, text cannot be copied, and the user cannot paste into the text field from the clipboard.*

**Allowing just the movement of text caret**

In case you want to disable cut/copy/paste actions, I suggest you look into [ToolbarOptions](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ToolbarOptions-class.html).